# What is the difference between Python Modules and Python Object oriented concepts?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and learning. I just have a simple question, What is the major difference between modules and inheritance, like we use inheritance to reuse the code and same thing can be done by importing modules.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inheritance is used for classes, modules are used for files.

Comment: Inheritance is not primarily about re-using code – that is just one possible usecase in practice. Since the topics of inheritance and modules is huge, can you perhaps narrow down what you are trying to ask? Note that open ended and opinion based questions that boil down to indiscriminate or subjective listings are generally not on-topic.